# Querying large dataset for statistics in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

Say I have a sample for which 5 million data objects are stored as rows in SQL Server. If I need to run some stats on the data, would it be better to have a table for each sample, or one giant table, where I would select by sample id and then run the stats?

There may eventually be hundreds or even thousands of samples- which seems like one massive table.

But I'm not a SQL Server expert so I can't say whether one would be faster than the other...

Or maybe a better way to deal with such a large data set? I was hoping to use SQL CLR with C# to do my heavy lifting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to deal with such a large dataset, my gut feeling tells me T-SQL and working in sets will be **significantly faster** than anything you can do in SQL-CLR and a RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) approach... dealing with large sets of data, summing up and selecting, that's what T-SQL is always been made for and what it's good at.

5 million rows isn't really an awful lot of data - it's a nice size dataset. But if you have the proper indices in place, e.g. on the columns you use in your `JOIN` conditions, in your `WHERE` clause and your `ORDER BY` clause, you should be just fine.

If you need more and more detailed advice - try to post your table structure, explain how you will query that table (what criteria you use for `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`) and we should be able to provide some more feedback.

Comment: Can I use T-SQL to perform the custom statistics I need? I've never used it before, so don't know. Any links to tutorials that are recommended?

I'm a C# guy so that's why the bent towards CLR :) I know what to do there... T-SQL is an unknown.

Comment: @Nicros: depends - what you might strive for is try to reduce the number of rows you're dealing with (by using T-SQL) and then apply the custom stats on this smaller data set. T-SQL is not exactly a statistics system....

Comment: Thank you marc.  For some stats, I might be able to break up the data into smaller chunks, but for some I will need all rows.  I'm curious about the performance of T-SQL vs CLR as well... I'm on the learning curve :)

Comment: I would like to see a discussion of this thread. I'm on a system which have have a 'lots of data'. Previous developer builded a whole system on t sql and hell of slow. Partly because every request from presentatiin re-run the heavy questions. My though is that there are no "here or there"-answer. Well-thoughted tsql which simplify (and break down to parts i.e. each customer and parallellism), then do aggregation in CLR.